# Rails 4, How to get through - has_many associations active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I modeling a three tables

**Event**, **EventEventCategory** and **EventCategory**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :event_event_categories
  has_many :event_categories, :through => :event_event_categories
  scope :live_event, ->{where(visible_status: 1)}

end

class EventEventCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :event_category

end

class EventCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :event_event_categories
  has_many :events, :through => :event_event_categories

end
```

And I get a event using live_event scope.

```
 @events = Event.live_event
```

And I wanna get a **live_event** 's category_lists

Now I get a Category list usgin below code

```
EventCategory.where("id in (?)", EventEventCategory.where("id in (?)", @events.pluck(:id).uniq))
```

or

```
EventCategory.where("id in (?)", @events.joins(:event_event_categories).pluck(:event_category_id).uniq)
```

is another command exist get a events category's list like a

### Event.live_events.event_categories

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @steveklein How to customize my command or get a event_categories at one command like  Event.live_events.event_categories

Comment: I believe you can do exactly that. However, Rails doesn't pluralize the scope names (I'm pretty sure the idiomatic scope name would just be "Event.live", which is why it doesn't pluralize. It's expecting an adjective. But that's a small thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventCategory.joins(:events).where(events: { visible_status: 1 })
```

maybe this one can help